# Listener not starting method properly

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin

In a vaadin scan application, i created a simple Listener:

```
public abstract class ScanEndListener {

    public abstract void onScanTerminated();    

}
```

and in my scan class, i created a scan array :

```
protected final Collection<ScanEndListener> scanEndListeners = new ArrayList<ScanEndListener>();
```

with a method called when the scan finishes :

```
private void notifyListeners(){
        for(ScanEndListener sl : scanEndListeners){
            sl.onScanTerminated();
        }
    }
```

In my view, i have a button with a clickListener:

```
final Button startScan = new Button(FontAwesome.PLAY);
                startScan.setImmediate(true);
                startScan.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        WhatWeb wat = new WhatWeb();
                        wat.addScanEndListener(new ScanEndListener() {  
                            @Override
                            public void onScanTerminated() {
                                new Notification("Scan terminated").show(Page.getCurrent());
                                System.out.println("Scan terminated");
                            }
                        });
                        wat.start(site);
                    }
                });
```

My problem is that i don't have my notification showed even if i have "Scan terminated" printed in console. I tried to do something else like `Page.getCurrent().reload()` but it did not work.

I also tried to create a method named test :

```
public void test(){
    Page.getCurrent().reload();
}
```

if i call `test()` in View.enter() method, it works perfectly, but if i call it in my onScanTerminated() listener method, it doesn't work.

I'm new to Listener system, but isn't it like a context problem? How can i do to make it work properly?

EDIT: The method `wat.start()` is running my scan in a new Thread, wich calls `notifyListeners()` when the scan is finished.

Comment: is your `WhatWeb.start()` running async?

Comment: yes, I edited question to explain it.

Comment: the server can not notify the client in this case.  you would have to use `Push`.

Comment: But the notification is working properly, because i have "Scan terminated" printed in my system.out

Comment: yes, but the client does not know about it.  i bet the notifications shows up when user does any action on the client after it get printed.

Comment: so how can i do? just saying `Push` is not helping me atm ^^" can you write a more detailed answer with some link(s) to an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running above code asynchronously, then the client will only happen to know about the state change eventually.  If you want to notify the client about the change, when it happened, then you would have to do this via [Server Push](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.push.html).

If the user is damned to wait anyway, then you could also use [Polling](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using%20polling), to let the client check the server in a given interval.

If you have heavy interaction by the user in the meantime, then you could as well just use above code, as the change will be seen by the user eventually.  In either case you should read the section about `Acessing UI from Another Thread` from above link about `Server Push`.